# Как удалить строчку из файла java

Tags: java

У меня есть файл BankAccount.txt как в нем имеются данные

```
Кредит:12500:1-
А что вы тут смотрите?:99999999:2-
Это надо закрыть:15428:3-
Люблю java:4850:4-
Долг Лехе:100050:5-
На отдых:2000:6-
```

После удаления 4 строки должно быть так

```
Кредит:12500:1-
А что вы тут смотрите?:99999999:2-
Это надо закрыть:15428:3-

Долг Лехе:100050:5-
На отдых:2000:6-
```

Общий код

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import static java.lang.String.valueOf;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JPanel mainPanel, createPanel, closePanel, atmPanel;
    JButton crBt, crBtBack, clBt, clBtBack, atmBt, atmBtBack, infoBt, crFinal, clFinal;
    JLabel nameBank, nameSScore, nameMScore, unicId;
    JTextField nameScore, moneyScore, idScore;

    public MainWindow() {
        //Имя окна
        super("Нае(Банк)");

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        createPanel = new JPanel();
        createPanel.setLayout(null);
        closePanel = new JPanel();
        closePanel.setLayout(null);
        atmPanel = new JPanel();
        atmPanel.setLayout(null);

        //Основная панель
        crBt = new JButton("Создать счет");
        crBt.setBounds(165, 150, 170, 25);
        crBt.setActionCommand("createScore");
        crBt.addActionListener(this);

        clBt = new JButton("Закрыть счет");
        clBt.setBounds(165, 200, 170, 25);
        clBt.setActionCommand("closeScore");
        clBt.addActionListener(this);

        atmBt = new JButton("Банкомат");
        atmBt.setBounds(165, 250, 170, 25);
        atmBt.setActionCommand("atm");
        atmBt.addActionListener(this);

        infoBt = new JButton("Информация о счетах");
        infoBt.setBounds(165, 300, 170, 25);
        infoBt.setActionCommand("getInfo");
        infoBt.addActionListener(this);

        nameBank = new JLabel("Нае(БАНК)");
        nameBank.setBounds(225, 100, 400, 30);

        //Создащая счета панель
        crBtBack = new JButton("Назад");
        crBtBack.setBounds(165, 400, 170, 25);
        crBtBack.setActionCommand("crBack");
        crBtBack.addActionListener(this);

        nameScore = new JTextField("", 10);
        nameScore.setBounds(165, 150, 170, 25);

        moneyScore = new JTextField("", 10);
        moneyScore.setBounds(165, 200, 170, 25);
        PlainDocument doc = (PlainDocument) moneyScore.getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter(new DigitFilter());

        crFinal = new JButton("Создать");
        crFinal.setBounds(165, 300, 170, 25);
        crFinal.setActionCommand("crFinal");
        crFinal.addActionListener(this);

        nameSScore = new JLabel("Имя счета");
        nameSScore.setBounds(225, 125, 400, 30);

        nameMScore = new JLabel("Стартовый капитал");
        nameMScore.setBounds(200, 175, 400, 30);


        //Закрывающая панель счета
        clBtBack = new JButton("Назад");
        clBtBack.setBounds(165, 400, 170, 25);
        clBtBack.setActionCommand("clBack");
        clBtBack.addActionListener(this);

        clFinal = new JButton("Закрыть счет");
        clFinal.setBounds(165, 300, 170, 25);
        clFinal.setActionCommand("clFinal");
        clFinal.addActionListener(this);

        idScore = new JTextField("", 10);
        idScore.setBounds(165, 200, 170, 25);
        PlainDocument doc1 = (PlainDocument) idScore.getDocument();
        doc1.setDocumentFilter(new DigitFilter());

        unicId = new JLabel("Уникальный идентификатор");
        unicId.setBounds(165, 175, 400, 30);

        //Панель банкомата


        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);


        getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.add(crBt);
        mainPanel.add(clBt);
        mainPanel.add(atmBt);
        mainPanel.add(infoBt);
        mainPanel.add(nameBank);
        setVisible(true);

        getContentPane().add(createPanel);
        createPanel.add(crBtBack);
        createPanel.add(nameScore);
        createPanel.add(moneyScore);
        createPanel.add(crFinal);
        createPanel.add(nameSScore);
        createPanel.add(nameMScore);
        setVisible(true);

        getContentPane().add(closePanel);
        closePanel.add(clFinal);
        closePanel.add(clBtBack);
        closePanel.add(idScore);
        closePanel.add(unicId);

        setVisible(true);

        getContentPane().add(atmPanel);
        setVisible(true);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("createScore".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            createPanel.setVisible(true);
            mainPanel.setVisible(false);
            closePanel.setVisible(false);
            atmPanel.setVisible(false);
        }
        if ("crBack".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            createPanel.setVisible(false);
            mainPanel.setVisible(true);
            closePanel.setVisible(false);
            atmPanel.setVisible(false);
        }
        if ("closeScore".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            createPanel.setVisible(false);
            mainPanel.setVisible(false);
            closePanel.setVisible(true);
            atmPanel.setVisible(false);
        }
        if ("clBack".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            createPanel.setVisible(false);
            mainPanel.setVisible(true);
            closePanel.setVisible(false);
            atmPanel.setVisible(false);
        }
        if ("crFinal".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("src/BankAccount.txt", true)) {

                writer.write(nameScore.getText() + ":" + moneyScore.getText() + ":" + (strLeight() + 1) + "-\n");
                writer.flush();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainWindow.this,
                        "Ваш счет " + nameScore.getText() + " создан с балансом " + moneyScore.getText() + "\nЕго уникальный идентификатор " + strLeight() + "\nСпасибо что используете наш банк", "Создание счета"
                        , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                nameScore.setText("");
                moneyScore.setText("0");

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }


        if ("getInfo".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainWindow.this,
                    "Тут будут счета",
                    "Информация о счетах\n"
                    , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        if ("clFinal".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("src/BankAccount.txt", true)) {

                System.out.println(idScore.getText());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainWindow();
    }

    public static int strLeight() {

        try {
            File myFile = new File("src/BankAccount.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(myFile);
            LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);

            int lineNumber = 0;

            while (lineNumberReader.readLine() != null) {
                lineNumber++;
            }

            lineNumberReader.close();
            return lineNumber;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }


    static class DigitFilter extends DocumentFilter {
        private static final String DIGITS = "\\d+";

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

            if (string.matches(DIGITS)) {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            if (string.matches(DIGITS)) {
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, string, attrs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Желательно что бы работал в этом куске кода

```
if ("clFinal".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("src/BankAccount.txt", true)) {
// Вот здесь
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Создать файл `BankAccount.tmp`, записать в него только нужные строки из `BankAccount.txt`, переименовать `BankAccount.txt`  в `BankAccount.bak`, переименовать `BankAccount.tmp` в `BankAccount.txt`

Comment: Приведи попытки написания желательного кода и расскажи что не получается?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы пытаетесь использовать текстовый файл для хранения ваших данных, то это очень плохая идея. Лучше сделайте класс-сервис, эмулирующий работу с базой данных, который для начала будет использовать коллекцию для хранения данных. Если хотите, то можете добавить сохранение этой коллекции на диск (хотя в этом случае лучше подключит бд). Что касается сохранения в файл, реализовать это достаточно несложно, но повторюсь : не стоит это использовать как БД.
Посему реализация такова: создаем класс - модель, хранящую инфу о идентификаторе, сумме и описании счета. Создаем класс - сервис, вмещающий логику работы с нашими данными (объектами класса-модели), в т.ч. эмулирующий БД. Класс-сервис будет иметь методы как для работы с нашей коллекцией (в дальнейшем БД), так и методы, создания тектового файла, его чтения и записи. Ну и правим вьюху. Я не делаю реализацию сервиса через интерфейс(хотя именно так и нужно делать), это останется на вашей совести, ровно как и подключение реальной БД.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3025189256705831368L;
    
    private final static String FILE_NAME = "BankAccount.txt";
    
    private final AccountService service;
    
    public MainWindow() {
        //Имя окна
        super("Нае(Банк)");
        this.service = new AccountService();
        
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        JPanel createPanel = new JPanel();
        createPanel.setLayout(null);
        JPanel closePanel = new JPanel();
        closePanel.setLayout(null);
        JPanel atmPanel = new JPanel();
        atmPanel.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel nameBank = new JLabel("Нае(БАНК)");
        nameBank.setBounds(225, 100, 400, 30);        
        JLabel nameSScore = new JLabel("Имя счета");
        nameSScore.setBounds(225, 125, 400, 30);
        JLabel nameMScore = new JLabel("Стартовый капитал");
        nameMScore.setBounds(200, 175, 400, 30);        
        JLabel unicId = new JLabel("Уникальный идентификатор");
        unicId.setBounds(165, 175, 400, 30);
        
        JTextField nameScore = new JTextField("", 10);
        nameScore.setBounds(165, 150, 170, 25);        
        JTextField moneyScore = new JTextField("", 10);
        moneyScore.setBounds(165, 200, 170, 25);
        addDigitFilter(moneyScore);        
        JTextField idScore = new JTextField("", 10);
        idScore.setBounds(165, 200, 170, 25);
        addDigitFilter(idScore);
        
        JButton crBt = createButton("Создать счет", 150, e -> setVisible(createPanel, mainPanel, closePanel, atmPanel));
        JButton clBt = createButton("Закрыть счет", 200, e -> setVisible(closePanel, createPanel, mainPanel, atmPanel));
        JButton atmBt = createButton("Банкомат", 250, e -> setVisible(atmPanel, createPanel, mainPanel, closePanel));
        JButton infoBt = createButton("Информация о счетах", 300, e -> showMessage("Информация о счетах\n", service.accountToString(service.findAll())));
        JButton crBtBack = createButton("Назад", 400, e -> setVisible(mainPanel, createPanel, closePanel, atmPanel));
        JButton clBtBack = createButton("Назад", 400, e -> setVisible(mainPanel, createPanel, closePanel, atmPanel));
        JButton crFinal = createButton("Создать", 300, e -> {
            try {                
                Account account = service.save(new Account(Long.valueOf(moneyScore.getText().trim()), nameScore.getText().trim()));
                service.writeFile(FILE_NAME);
                
                showMessage("Создание счета", 
                        "Ваш счет " + account.getComment() + 
                        " создан с балансом " + account.getAmount() + 
                        "\nЕго уникальный идентификатор " + account.getId() + 
                        "\nСпасибо что используете наш банк");
                
                nameScore.setText("");
                moneyScore.setText("0");
                
            } catch (IOException | RuntimeException ex) {
                showMessage("Ошибка", ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
        JButton clFinal = createButton("Закрыть счет", 300, e -> {
            try {
                service.deleteById(Long.valueOf(idScore.getText()));
                service.writeFile(FILE_NAME);
                showMessage("Закрытие счета", "Счет №" + idScore.getText() + " закрыт");
                idScore.setText("0");
            } catch (IOException | RuntimeException ex) {
                showMessage("Ошибка", ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
        
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        
        this.addPanel(mainPanel, crBt, clBt, atmBt, infoBt, nameBank)
            .addPanel(createPanel, crBtBack, nameScore, moneyScore, crFinal, nameSScore, nameMScore)
            .addPanel(closePanel, clFinal, clBtBack, idScore, unicId)
            .addPanel(atmPanel, crBtBack);// добавляем в аргументах нужные компоненты
        
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JButton createButton(String label, int y, Consumer<ActionEvent> consumer){
        final JButton button = new JButton(label);
        button.setBounds(165, y, 170, 25);
        button.addActionListener(e -> consumer.accept(e));
        return button;
    }
    
    private MainWindow addPanel(JPanel panel, Component ... components){
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        for (Component component : components) panel.add(component);
        setVisible(true);
        return this;
    }

    private void setVisible(Component visibleComponent, Component... invisibleComponents) {
        for (Component component : invisibleComponents) component.setVisible(false);
        visibleComponent.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private void showMessage(String title, String message) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainWindow.this,
                message, title,
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    
    private void addDigitFilter(JTextComponent component){
        ((PlainDocument) component.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DigitFilter());
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new MainWindow());
    }

    static class DigitFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        private static final String DIGITS = "\\d+";

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            if (string.matches(DIGITS)) super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            if (string.matches(DIGITS)) super.replace(fb, offset, length, string, attrs);
        }
        
    }
    
}

class AccountService {

    private final Map<Long, Account> accounts = new TreeMap<>();
    
    private Long ID_COUNTER = 0L;
    
    public void deleteById(Long id){
        accounts.remove(id);
    }
    
    public Optional<Account> findById(Long id){
        return accounts.containsKey(id) ? Optional.of(accounts.get(id)) : Optional.empty();
    }
    
    public Collection<Account> findAll (){
        return accounts.values();
    }
    
    public Account save(Account account){
        account.setId(++ID_COUNTER);
        accounts.put(ID_COUNTER, account);
        return account;
    }
    
    public long count(){
        return accounts.size();
    }
    
    
    public String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            return stream.collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n"));
        }
    }

    public void writeFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), accountToString(accounts.values()).getBytes(), CREATE, WRITE);
    }
    
    public String accountToString(Collection<Account> accounts) {
        return accounts.stream()
                .map(Account::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n"));
    }
    
}

class Account {
    
    private Long id;
    private Long amount;
    private String comment;

    public Account(Long amount, String comment) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.comment = comment;
    }
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Long amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return comment + ":" + amount + ":" + id;
    }
    
}
```